# Tableau: I need to display up to six different views of the same choropleth map in the same map, with a user able to choose which view to display

Tags: tableau-api, choropleth, tableau-desktop

TL;DR Choropleth Map with city-shapes being colored in either red or green based on input (poll result), with several different inputs and a user should be able to choose which input to display on the map.

I have a problem with tableau that I do not know how to solve and I do not know what to search for to see tutorials on it, so hopefully you people can help me!

I live in Switzerland and we have regular votes/polls. Usually, there are between 3 and 6 polls at a time. I want to create a choropleth map for my district (18 cities/communities) to display the voting results - if a poll passes it should be green, otherwhise red. (yes votes > 50%)

I can do that for each poll individually, but I want one map, where the user can click on the name of the vote to display these results. So one map, a filter box (or something similar) on the right side with the names of the polls in it to click on them.

Is that even possible? Someone suggested I take a look at parameters, but the only thing I could do there was to filter between yes and no for a single poll.

The data I use is in excel with the follwoing format:

| City | Poll 1 Yes | Poll 1 No | Poll 2 Yes | Poll 2 No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City 1 | 54% | 46% | 61% | 39% |
| City 2 | 45% | 55% | 63% | 37% |

So a user should be able to choose if poll 1 or poll 2 is displayed. With this number, if poll 1 is chosen to be displayed, City 1 should be green and city 2 should be red. If poll 2 is chosen, both cities should be green.

I can manipulate the excel file, so that only the yes votes for each poll are written in there, that would be no problem.

I can also rearange the columns and rows if that is needed. I don't need to filter for cities or yes/no, only for the polls.

Here is a picture/mockup of how I imagine it:
[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Best solution probably involves restructured data. For example one column for the poll name; one for yes%; one for no% and one for city name. Then a single filter can select the poll leaving a list of yes/no % by city and (assuming yes+no=100%) a single column to colour the cities.